# Deleting items from a UICollectionView layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a query running on viewDidScroll and a flag gets set when the data comes back empty.  This flag will then call the function below with the last index that had valid data:

```
- (void) endOfDataReached:(NSInteger) indexToRemove
{   
    [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{

        // Loop through end of threshold
        for (int i = indexToRemove; i < indexToRemove + 30; i++)
        {
            [self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexToRemove inSection:0]]];
        }
    }
    completion:^(BOOL finished)
    {
        // Finished
    }];
}
```

The above code removes a lot more than the last indexes that I want it to remove.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.